# jQuery Mobile issu on data-rel="back". And how to highlight the coresponding list item in left panel of split view when returns back to previous page

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have implemented an application using ***`jQuery on PhoneGap.`***

In that I'm using a **split view with two panels left& right.**

in left panel when *I select a list item for page 1 it shows the page1 in Right panel.*

[image]

in page 1 I have a button "**page1 info==>**" that moves page1 to the detailed information of page1 in next page.

[image]

in detailed page I have a back "**xPage1**" button which returns to the previous page i.e. page1.

in back button implementation I have a **condition** that **I couldn't used id of page to return to page 1**

as **`href="#page1"`**

`<a href="#page1" id="" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" class="ui-btn-left"  data-theme="c">Page1</a>`

So I used **`data-rel="back"`**

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" class="ui-btn-left"  data-theme="c">Page1</a>
```

yes it return to the previous page fine.

[image]

but when we returns the selected button on page1 its **`stay highlighted so longer`**. it is due to **`data-rel="back"`** .

***I need two requirements here***

1. **Button s'd not highlighted so longer** as shown above.
2. **The highlight active focus on selected item on left panel but not on the button of right panel**  as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving `data-rel="back"`, just give in the href link of **Go to Pg-1** in **xPage1**. And make the Button highlight in default.

Comment: Thats what im saying in condition..! in back button implementation i have a condition that i couldn't used id of page1 to return to page 1